# why each mongodb replica set should have a distinct replSetName value, when application connects to these multiple replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I am deploying multiple mongdb replica set, and wondering should I give each set a unique replSetName?

I have read the suggestion on mongodb offical document about choosing unique replSetName for each set. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication.replSetName

So I'am curious to know "what drivers may group replica set connections by replica set name ?".

Comment: It's best practice to not use duplicated replica set name when you're connecting to more than one of them at once. As with all best practice recommendations, you're not forced to follow them, but it might help to prevent confusion in the future when troubleshooting issues.

Answer (score 0):

For the below reason:
1. mongo doesn't allow you to assign same name to all members of the replicaset
2. To easily identify which node is impacted or having problem

Clarify:
1. Why do you want to assign the same name to all nodes of the replica set?

In your driver's connection string, you must mention name and port of all members of the replica set to achieve HA so that it can automatically connect to the new Primary node

Comment: Thanks for your reply. however I believe  that the replication.replSetName option is a global setting for all members of the replica set, as the document mentions "all hosts in the replica set must have the same set name".

Comment: And to clarify, I got the idea of assign the same name to multiple replica sets (not just for all nodes in only one replica set) just for simplicity of ansible deployment.